# Numerical Approximations for optimum epsilon Multi-Armed-Bandit

Tags: multiarmed-bandit

Aside from raw simulation, are there numerical approximations of cumulative reward curves for epsilon-greedy bandits with bernoulli arms? Specifically, I would like to approximate these reward curves as a function of $\epsilon$ and up to say, 6 bernoulli arms with probabilities $p_1,...,p_6$.

Comment: The simulations are very easy - is there a reason you don't want to run them?  I am a bit confused why you are considering fixed $\epsilon$, since this gives worst-case expected regret $\epsilon T$ (choosing the same arm every time gets you O(T) expected regret).

Comment: @combo: Epsilon can vary as a decaying function of iteration. The simulations are easy to code but require many, many runs to get a sense of how well on average the MAB does. This is especially true if the probabilities are quite small. It just seems barbaric to have to manually simulate across many values of epsilon to get a sense of which epsilon gives the best short term return.

Comment: And by "which epsilon gives the best short term return", you mean which function?

Comment: @combo: I'm fine for now with a fixed epsilon solution. Ideally if I could put in an arbitrary decay function on epsilon then it would output a numerical approximation and tell me which starting value of epsilon is optimal for that decay function.

Comment: I still think that the appropriate "numerical approximation" is to just run the simulation.  In my time studying bandits I did not come across any short-time numerical analysis besides running simulations. I am sure that you could find special cases where you can get snappy analysis, but those will break down very quickly as you add in decays and arbitrary success probabilities. If you want a starter implementation in julia I could throw one together for you in a few minutes.